# How do I update a placeholder image with an async image?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using a manager class to either pull images from a cache or make a network request. I'm using a placeholder image. What's the best way to replace that placeholder image when the proper image is retrieved?

```
final ItemManager _manager;
final Item _item;
var _itemImage =
  new Image.asset('assets/images/icons/ic_placeholder.png');

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _loadImage();
  return new Container(
    child: _itemImage,
  );
}

_loadImage() async {
  var file = await _manager.itemImageForImageUrl(_item.imageUrl);
  _stickerImage = new Image.file(file);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) class is designed for cases like this. I would modify `_loadImage` to return the image instead of setting a member variable. Then you can get rid of `initState` and modify your `build()` method as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FutureBuilder(
    future: _loadImage(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> image) {
      if (image.hasData) {
        return image.data;  // image is ready
      } else {
        return new Container();  // placeholder
      }
    },
  );
}
```

As an aside, you should never mutate member variables of your `State` without calling `setState`. Your build function won't be called and this is something that the linter will eventually complain about (as soon as we implement it). But `FutureBuilder` is a much better fit for your use case because you won't have to worry about what happens if your State is disposed by the time the image finishes loading.

Comment: @alardizabal adding to the comment about setState, as you call `_loadImage` in the build function, the setState would result in the build method being called again resulting in _loadImage being called again. Using that construction you should call _loadImage in initState.

Comment: Can you please rewrite the _loadImage function?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [flutter_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_image) "to load images from the network with a retry mechanism."

You can pair it with a placeholder like this:

```
new FadeInImage(
  placeholder: _itemImage,
  image: new NetworkImageWithRetry('https://example.com/img.jpg'),
),
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I have images in async await function. How can I display the dynamic images.