# Flutter display image from a post API

Tags: flutter, post, flutter-image

I'm using a POST request (with a json body) to retrieve a png image (a qr code).
How could I display such image? I checked with image.network but it seems it only handles GET request.

Answer (score 2):

If your response body are png image bytes, then you can try using Image.memory constructor as follows

```
Image img = Image.memory(response.bodyBytes).image;
```

You should check out [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) and also [MemoryImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [FutureBuilder](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-futurebuilder-383b6ed63f18) for that - the `http.post` returns a `Future<Response>` which you need to decode to get to your image url from the response body. (Pass the `http.post` call to a decoding function returning a `Future<String>` which is your final image url).

As soon as the Future is resolved you can then build the Image using Image.network

Also have a look at this: [How do I update a placeholder image with an async image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290680/how-do-i-update-a-placeholder-image-with-an-async-image) as it seems to be related.